# Problem loading LaTeX KOMA-script and fontspec after freshly installing vanilla texlive

Tags: 13.10, package-management, compiling, latex, texlive

I have just installed vanilla TeXlive according to [the TUG instructions](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) on my Ubuntu 13.10.

A standard minimal example properly compiles the way it is supposed to do:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

However, as soon as I start loading one of the KOMA classes or the `fontspec` package, it won't compile:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

When trying to compile this example with LuaLaTeX, it will give me the following error message:

> *! LaTeX Error: File `scrartcl.cls' not found.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

And compiling this example with LuaLaTeX returns:

> *! LaTeX Error: File `fontspec.sty' not found.*

I am confused about this because I thought that both `fontspec`and `koma-script` are standard parts of TeXlive. Also, when I type `texdoc fontspec` or `texdoc scrguien` in the terminal, I **do** get the proper manual for the respective packages.

**EDIT:**

The KOMA classes (e.g.  `scrartcl.cls`) are saved in the directory where the `install-tl`-Script installed them by default:
`/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script`

`fontspec.sty` is saved in:
`/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec`

The `lualatex` compiler can be found in:
`/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/`

Now comes the interesting part, the respective permissions:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 127355 Dez 27 00:18 scrartcl.cls`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9565 Mai 22  2013 fontspec.sty`
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        6 Aug 15  2009 lualatex -> luatex`

Comment: Since you did not install TeX Live from the repositories you might be missing permissions to access the `.cls` file, or simply have it some place not accessible by the compiler. Please expand your post detailing where you have the compiler installed, where the KOMA library is and the permissions on the `.cls` file.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I added the locations and the permissions to the post.

Could the missing executable permissions be the problem? And how can I make all classes in the `/usr/local/texlive` subdirectories executable at once? I would prefer not to do it one by one.

Comment: The permissions look right, none of these files need to be executable, only readable by the compiler. Then this might be related to a missing path. The installation from the repos does not require it, but I believe the manual install does: did you modify the PATH environment variable?

Comment: Shot in the dark: there is some problem with your texinputs path or the ls-lr database. Try to run `sudo mktexlsr`. Have you set a local TEXINPUTS variable?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I did do ` PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` after installing. This location was the one the script told me after successfully installing TeXlive.
  
@Rmano I just ran `sudo mktexlsr` and it apparently updated something, but it didn't change anything about my problem, even after restarting. I have not set a local TEXINPUTS variable (at least not manually). How do I do that?

Comment: I also tried `sudo texhash` several times in combination with restarting, but it doesn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just [completely removed everything related to TeXlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu) and reinstalled vanilla TeXlive from scratch according to this [StackExchange user's guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu). Now, I am not experiencing the problem any more, even though I had tried to install according to this guide before.

Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: One last thought on this: I had `lilypond`and `frescobaldi` installed on this computer before, which I now completely removed before reinstalling TeXlive. I am not sure, but maybe this did the trick.